# display:inline-block not working

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

You know how on tumblr, the posts on your main page scrolls vertically? I want to do it horizontally. I know I have to use some type of display:inline or display:inline block somewhere. I tried it in my body tag, postbox tag, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: post what you have tried. I don't use tumblr, so no, I don't know how it works...

Answer (score 0):

Width in CSS doesn't quite work the same way as height does, and by default, content will always break on whitespace to stay within the width of it's parent.

You can, however, force an element to not wrap any of it's child elements by using `white-space: nowrap;`

This, in conjunction with `overflow-x: scroll;` will keep those elements inside a nice scrollable area, rather that pushing out the boundaries of their container.

You were on the right track with using `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` for keeping the content on the same line.. you could also use `float` as another alternative, or even table-cell display properties, but those should be a bit more case specific.

Here's an example that I put together, hopefully that should be all that you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xkPP/